# Xcode: Autolayout not working correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, pagecontrol

I've got this weird bug in my application. When I load up my app on the simulator or an iDevice and I go to the pageControl page the layout is doing weird things.

I use the pagecontrol pages for a calendar view, so if I load it up I see this

[image: first view]

That's all good, but when I scroll down (or up) the layout changes a bit

[image: While scrolling]

If the scrolling is done and I'm on the next page the layout readjust itself and is then in it's good state

[image: 2nd page]

So I don't know where this has gone wrong but of someone knows I would be very grateful!
I'm using auto-layout in this page and on every simulator size I get this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto-layout to position the vertical line, then I suggest you base it's position off of the left side of the cell rather than the right side of the label to the left of the cell.